# TypeError: '_asyncio.Future' object is not subscriptable, using async motor driver for mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, discord.py, motordriver

I have a code where I try to update a user's data whenever he posts a new message:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if isinstance(message.channel, discord.DMChannel):
        return
    collection = db[f"{message.guild.id}"]
    coll = db.guilds
    if message.author.bot:
        return
    else:
        if message.channel.id != 796145301013397544:
            if not await coll.count_documents({"_id": message.guild.id}):
                await coll.insert_one({"_id": message.guild.id, "suggest_channel": "None", "message_coins": 0.5, "log_channel": "None", 'prefix': '.', 'ignore_channel': 'None', 'likes': 0})
            message_coins = await coll.find_one({"_id": message.guild.id})["message_coins"]
            if not await collection.count_documents({"_id": message.author.id}):
                await collection.insert_one({"_id": message.author.id, "msg": 0, "happy": 0, "coins": 0, "badge": "Нет", "cookie": 0, "minvoice": 0, "color": 0xFFFFFF, "osebe": "Отсутствует", "age": "Неизвестно"})
            await collection.update_one({"_id": message.author.id}, {"$inc": {"msg": 1}})
            await collection.update_one({"_id": message.author.id}, {"$inc": {"coins": message_coins}})
        else:
            pass
    await bot.process_commands(message)
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(on_message(message))
```

but, when it is activated, I get an TypeError:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
await coro(*args, **kwargs)
File "/app/bot.py", line 187, in on_message
message_coins = await coll.find_one({"_id": message.guild.id})["message_coins"]
TypeError: '_asyncio.Future' object is not subscriptable
```

how can this TypeError be fixed?

Comment: you are trying to subscript the future object you need to put brackets around it to subscript the awaited object like `message_coins = (await coll.find_one({"_id": message.guild.id}))["message_coins"]`

Comment: Thank you very much, but there is a new error:
`await asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(on_message(message))
RuntimeError: This event loop is already running`

Comment: That is a new problem. You should close this question and open a new one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue here is in the nature that python will interpret this line of code

```py
message_coins = await coll.find_one({"_id": message.guild.id})["message_coins"]
```

It will see as call the find_one method on the coll object, use subscript to get the "message_coins" element, then pass that object to `await`. However this is not what you actually want.

```py
message_coins = (await coll.find_one({"_id": message.guild.id}))["message_coins"]
```

You need to use perenthesis to force the order of operations here. So by wrapping the await and the method call it tells python to pass that to `await` then once you get the final result back from the await call you then use subscript to locate the "message_coins" element.